# How to analyze if cronjobs are running in a centos server?

Tags: linux, centos

How can I check if certain cronjob is running in my centos server?
I have written various crons in centos. Some of those crons are not running even though the interval is set properly. Is there a way to check the crons if its running in behind or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see what's crond launching, check the cron log:

```
less /var/log/cron
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities to see all active cronjobs. The easiest way is probably to run execute `crontab -l` as the `root` user.

You can also filter for cronjobs executed by a certain user with (execute the command as root/with `sudo`)

```
crontab -u <username> -l
```

To see the jobs running from the `/etc/crontab` file, look at it with `less /etc/crontab`.

The folders `/etc/cron.weekly/`,`cd /etc/cron.hourly/` and `cd /etc/cron.daily/` can contain files that are executed weekly, hourly and daily as well.